# Get env variables with Dockerized Vue app in Dokku

Tags: docker, vue.js, environment-variables, dokku

I have created a Vue project using Docker (and Docker Compose) and am in the process of deploying with Dokku. I have configured the project enough that it can deploy successfully in production. However, I am running into trouble when trying to access environment variables in the Vue CLI build script. Due to the way the Vue CLI works, environment variables are essentially built into the app **at build time** (not runtime). This means that I need the environment variables at the time the app is being compiled, which I manage through a production `Dockerfile`.

The [Auth0 Dokku Guide](https://auth0.com/blog/hosting-applications-using-digitalocean-and-dokku/) was invaluable **but** did not deal with passing environment variables from Dokku to the Vue CLI when building (where I am stuck). With Docker Compose (development) this is easy, but a Dockerfile (production) seems to be different (utilizing **both** `ARG` and `ENV` for **every** variable needed).

```sh
# === Base stage =====
FROM node:12.2-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
# node_modules are managed inside the container
COPY package*.json ./

# === Dependency stage =====
FROM base AS dependencies
# Install ONLY production dependencies
RUN npm install --only=production
# Copy production dependencies aside
RUN cp -R node_modules prod_node_modules
# Install ALL dependencies
RUN npm install

# === Build stage =====
FROM dependencies AS build
# Copy the rest of the application
COPY . .

# NOTE: It appears to be necessary to use BOTH 'ARG' and 'ENV'?
ARG VUE_APP_API_URL
ENV VUE_APP_API_URL ${VUE_APP_API_URL}
# ...repeat for EVERY build variable necessary?

# Build the Vue application, outputting the static files to /dist
RUN npm run build

# === Release stage =====
FROM base AS release
# Copy production dependencies (overwriting all dependencies, used for building)
COPY --from=dependencies /app/prod_node_modules ./node_modules
# Copy the build artifacts from the build stage
COPY --from=build /app/dist ./dist
# Copy the simple server file
COPY server.js /app/server.js
EXPOSE 8080
CMD node server.js
```

The key part is the `ARG` and `ENV` usage...is there not a better way than repeating this for every variable used in the Vue build process (ie. app config file)?

```sh
# NOTE: It appears to be necessary to use BOTH 'ARG' and 'ENV'?
ARG VUE_APP_API_URL
ENV VUE_APP_API_URL ${VUE_APP_API_URL}
# ...repeat for EVERY build variable necessary?
```

The app builds successfully and is properly deployed in a small Express server container. The environment variables are populated upon the Vue CLI build when using the above Dockerfile setup. I use a `config.js` file in the Vue project to get the environment variables at build time. Note the proper usage of `VUE_APP_` variable prefixes (required by Vue CLI).

```js
export default {
  api: {
    url: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
  },
  app: {
    envName: process.env.VUE_APP_ENV_NAME || "local",
    isProduction: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
  },
};
```

I have tried adding the necessary environment variables both as Dokku `config` variables and `docker-options` variables. I am a little confused about the [Dokku docs](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/methods/dockerfiles/#build-time-configuration-variables) on build time configuration variables. Does this refer to variables used solely in the Dockerfile, or variables essentially provided as `process.env`?

```sh
# Set Dokku environment variables (NOT USED)
dokku config:set [app_name] VUE_APP_API_URL=https://api.example.org

# Set Docker build variable (USED WITH ARG/ENV)
dokku docker-options:add [app_name] build "--build-arg VUE_APP_API_URL=https://api.example.org"
```

There must be a better way to pass the environment variables through, rather than taking up so many lines (and stages) in the Dockerfile!

**TL;DR:** Is there any better way to pass environment variables from Dokku to the Vue CLI build script when building with a `Dockerfile`? It seems crazy to have to update the production Dockerfile with so many `ARG` and `ENV` declarations, then still have to set each one individually in `dokku docker-options` with that long-winded syntax!

**TL;DR2:** Why doesn't it work with `dokku config`, since I am not using buildtime variables but the Vue CLI is using the current environment variables to build the app? Why does the Vue CLI use the `dokku config` variables when building?

Comment: Hello! I'm actually facing the exact same problem as you. Just wondering if you've managed to find a nice and clean solution?

Comment: I didn't unforunately, but thankfully there weren't many variables the app needs (at least, right now...). Let me know if you find a better solution!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a better way to pass those variables in during build time (docker build). This is done purposely, as docker images should not have secrets baked in.

If anything, it might be a good idea to move that config into a file that gets generated on app start, at which point it would be runtime config (docker run).

This is based on Dockerfile best practices, as shown [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/13490).

Might be a good feature request to enable setting all config variables as build args.

Comment: I completely agree with you that secrets should not be baked into Docker images! I understand their current approach in that context, although it is unfortunate that an app with multiple config variables (that are not secrets) requires so many build stage arguments (but this is a Vue CLI build issue).